# How to connect to newly installed Oracle XE instance?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-xe

I have installed Oracle XE on Win7 x64 machine. Installation completed successfully without problem, or perhaps installer didn't tell about them. But after installation I can't connect to database; its web interface is not working. I have looked through list of open ports, and there is no 8080 port as was noted during installation. Also I can't connect via SQLPlus.

```
SQL> connect SYSTEM
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12638: Credential retrieval failed
```

Somewhere in the web it was told to edit `sqlnet.ora` file, I have changed it in the following way:

```
# SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)
```

and now I get next error

```
SQL> connect SYSTEM
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
```

What do I need to change so that I can connect to it?

Comment: I also have the same issue (Windows 7 64 bit, Oracle 10 g XE). I also initially "ORA-12638: Credential retrieval failed". after setting 'SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)' I am getting 'ORA-01034: ORACLE not available ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist'

Comment: Look at Rejeev's answer. Since your Oracle install was done with NTS authentication, it couldn't create the XE database. Hence you get the ORACLE not available errors. You can see this in the oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\config\log files.

Answer (score 8):

I figured out the issue. 
I was using domain login to install Oracle XE. If you are using domain login to install Oracle XE then the database creation will fail (though you may not get any error messages on that regard). 
Solution:
Install Oracle using a local admin user. 
Change SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES to (NONE) in sqlnet.ora. 
Now login with your domain user to use oracle XE.

Comment: Here is the link to official docs mentioning this problem: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/install.102/b25143/toc.htm#BABJCEDD

Answer (score 2):

Check the Oracle services are started

Answer (score 2):

Did you set your ORACLE_SID environment variable to the name of the instance you're connecting to?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure oracle service is started.
2. did to ran netca after installation?  - if not you can ran it from cmd
3. You can't connect using system if the instacne is down only as sysdba (user sys)
4. Make sure your ORACLE_HOME,ORACLE_SID,PATH environment variables are ok
5. If everything was ok then you can try to start/connect to the instance manually

Sample:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\asafm>
C:\Documents and Settings\asafm>
C:\Documents and Settings\asafm>sqlplus "sys as sysdba"

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri May 11 16:21:42

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  535662592 bytes
Fixed Size                  1375792 bytes
Variable Size             360710608 bytes
Database Buffers          167772160 bytes
Redo Buffers                5804032 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL>
SQL>
SQL>select status from v$instance;
```

Answer (score 1):

As Rejeev Divakaran said, installing oracle XE with local windows user, and switching back to domain user account, started db, able to connect.

Config

- Office Laptop
- Windows 7 64 Bit
- Oracle 11g XE

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect this way from the command line:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

if so at the SQL prompt enter

```
SQL>startup
```

If the command returns ok then try to connect with a username and password.

Answer (score 0):

This error message usually occurs when the database could not be started. The windows service may be running, but still Oracle might not be able to spawn server threads and hand out client connections.

Have a Look into app\oracle\admin\xe\bdump\alert_xe.log for any error messages during the last start of the Oracle service.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is as "lucky" as me: I recently couldn't install Oracle with a local user (as suggested here before) because the target machine (Win2k8 x64) was also the Domain Controller of that network.
All users were in domain - no local users available :(

Here are the steps I performed:

- Installed Oracle XE in my local machine (that works fine). Made a backup (using the built-in `backup.bat`);
- Transferred the `fast_recovery_area` folder to my target machine;
- Installed the Oracle XE in the target machine normally;
- Edited the `%ORA_HOME%\network\admin\sqlnet.ora` file and performed [this well-known edit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11019158/666104):

  `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)`
- Edited the `%ORA_HOME%\bin\restore.bat` file:

  - Replaced every entry `rman target / (...)` by `rman target sys/MySysDbaPass (...)`
  - Replaced every entry `(...) connect / as sysdba^;` by `(...) connect sys/MySysDbaPass as sysdba^;`
- Runned restore.bat - when prompted, pointed to the `fast_recovery_area` I've transferred before.
- Done! (*pheew!*)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering this YEARS old question, but I managed to make it work...

Make sqlnet.ora change.

Run StopDB.bat

Run MakeDB.bat

This will create a demo database, reset the password to 'oracle', and will also allow you to connect without error.