# Oracle 11g XE - Can't login and database is down

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

Just installed Oracle 11g XE (Windows), but can't connect in SQL Developer or run any command in CLI.
When try to `connect` in CLI using `SYS` or `SYSTEM` with password defined during the install, get the following error:

> ORA-12638: credential retrieval failed

When I tray to connect via SQL Developer (tried via SID and Service Name, hostname=localhost, port=1521, SID=xe), get this error:

> Status : Listener refused the connection with the following error:
>   ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in
>   connect descriptor

Already tried change `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)` to `(NONE)` in **sqlnet.ora** file. When I do this, get the following error when try to `connect` with the `SYS` or `SYSTEM` user and password:

> ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
>
> ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist

Already tried every solution in Google results, like reinstall, stop and start services... Mostly ask for first connect in CLI to make some changes, but even this I can't accomplish.

Any suggestions on how connect to the database?

Comment: Well, we have no idea what, exactly, you did or what diagnostic feedback you might have gotten.  I'd want to see that feedback.  I'd want to see the messages associated with the startup, as found in the alert log 'alertXE.log'.

Comment: Did you install using default values for everything? For instance, did you name the database anything other than "xe"? Try following Oracle's guide to connect using SQLPlus and SQL Developer and let us know if you customized anything during the installation, as that may have an impact on the connection details that you are using. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18147/tdddg_connecting.htm#TDDDG99996

Comment: Some of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/381086/266304) might be helpful, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @1991DBA Every setting was default in the installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution:

I was installing in my company Windows user domain.

1. First uninstall any instance of Oracle XE 11g.
2. Switch to a **local** administrator Windows user and install Oracle XE 11g.
3. Sign off and back to company Windows user.
4. Edit the file **C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora** (or equivalent to your installation path). Change `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (TNS)` to `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)`.
   This change will allow you connect to database from you company Windows user.

As seen here: [Error ORA-12638 in Oracle Database 11g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463516/error-ora-12638-in-oracle-database-11g)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: Open command window, cd to Oracle bin directory, enter sqlplus /nolog.  If you get a prompt enter connect / as sysdba.  If you get connected then you can try "startup".
- -
Did you try to start the Oracle RDBMS service via Services (services.msc)?

Comment: I can't login, in any way. Every time I got the ORA-12638: credential retrieval failed error. All Oracle related services are running.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use an spfile?  Check the registry for ORA_SID_NAME_PFILE that is different from default location of $ORACLE_HOME/dbs.  Also check the default location. Use only the default location or the registry entry removing either the registry entry or the file in the default location depending on which you want to use.